# Button background next to button border styling

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons next to each other. One of them has a background and the other has a transparent background with a border. The problem is the border is visually outside the button, making it slightly larger than the primary button.

I have searched and come across many solutions for this, but my question is what is the best practice to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

use `box-sizing`

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This way the padding, border will be inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, one is to use outline and outline offset, like this:

```
button{
 outline: 1px solid red;
 outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

Or you can use an inset box-shadow, like this:

```
button{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px red;
}
```